# Understanding code open_clientfd(char *hostname, char *port) from book CSAPP? : issue for argument hostname and port

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

As reading the book < Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective > and in the chapter of Network Programming, I saw a this function:

```
int open_clientfd(char *hostname, char *port) {
int clientfd;
struct addrinfo hints, *listp, *p;

/* Get a list of potential server addresses */
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  /* Open a connection */
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;  /* ... using a numeric port arg. */
hints.ai_flags |= AI_ADDRCONFIG;  /* Recommended for connections */
Getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &listp);

/* Walk the list for one that we can successfully connect to */
for (p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {

    /* Create the socket descriptor */
    if ((clientfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) < 0) 
        continue; /* Socket failed, try the next */
    if (connect(clientfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) != -1) 
        break; /* Success */
    Close(clientfd); /* Connect failed, try another */
} 

/* Clean up */
Freeaddrinfo(listp);
if (!p) /* All connects failed */
    return -1;
else    /* The last connect succeeded */
    return clientfd
}
```

In this function, the book said "The open_clientfd function establishes a connection with a server running on host hostname and listening for connection requests on port number port."

Therefore, I understand that hostname is for client and port is for server on client-server transaction.

My doubt come from the code, Getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &listp);

Since getaddrinfo's host and service arguments are the two components of a socket address(as the book said), I think this open_clientfd function only work when client and server are on the same host.

Am I right?
What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the significance of `host` and `port` is not correct.

A server runs an specific host *and* a specific port. So the combination of `host` *and* `port` identifies a single server.

`Getaddrinfo` returns a list of (ip, port) combinations to try, using DNS to translate the host name to a list of IP addresses if needed. The function then tries to connect them one by one until one succeeds.

And it works no matter where the server runs.

Comment: Thanks now I perfectly understand it.